# Gluon SceneBuilder 8.1.1 Problems using Include or Import FXML

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I cannot include a simple fxml file into a BorderPane or TabPane.
Details including some sample code are already reported here: 
https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/68/various-problems-trying-to-inlcude-an-fxml

I still have a few questions according this topic:

1. Is there a limitation of containers where you may fx:include into ? (e.g. are TabPanes not allowed??)
2. Is there some specific thing I had to do inside the included FXML file which I am missing?
3. Any other hint?

If you experience the same problems - maybe you could vote for the bug, so we increase the chances to get a fix.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you *include* one FXML file into another using Scene Builder menu `File -> Include -> FXML...`, the included file is added under the root, according the following [code](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/src/f4fe56d8669a57b505030c639266551cf0036c68/src/main/java/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/editor/job/IncludeFileJob.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#IncludeFileJob.java-89):

```
final FXOMObject rootObject = targetDocument.getFxomRoot();
if (rootObject != null) {
    final Selection selection = getEditorController().getSelection();
    if (selection.isEmpty() || selection.isSelected(rootObject)) {
        targetObject = rootObject;
    } else {
        targetObject = selection.getAncestor();
    }        
    ...
}
```

In the case of your `AnchorWithTabPane.fxml` file, if you don't select anything, it will be included under the root:

```
<AnchorPane ...>
   <children>
     <TabPane  .../>
     <fx:include source="UserControl.fxml" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Now, if you select `TabPane`, going through the else condition, it will go again under the root, giving that the tabPane's ancestor is the root itself.

If you select `Tab`, the ancestor is `TabPane`, but there you can't include a FXML node.

If you select the `AnchorPane` of a tab, the ancestor is the tab, and you can't include there a FXML node either.

So the solution or workaround in this case is adding some inner container or node to that anchor pane, and then selecting it: since its ancestor will be the `AnchorPane`, it will add the FXML node there.

[image: include trick]

And finally you can delete that *temporary* container/node.

As a result, you will have:

```
<TabPane ...>
    <tabs>
      <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane ...>
                 <children>
                    <fx:include source="UserControl.fxml" />
                 </children>
          </AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
        </content>
      </Tab>
    </tabs>
```

Regarding your question about what containers can hold an `fx:include`, all the panes under `javafx.scene.layout.*` can hold them.

As hint, if you use NetBeans, edit an fxml file, and within the container tags click Ctrl+space, it will show you if the `fx:include` node is allowed:

[image: fx:include]

Comment: The same approach seems to also work in Scene Builder 11